# Xamarin.forms listview with pull to refresh and New itens on top

Tags: facebook, listview, xamarin, refresh, pull

I'm  kind new to Xamarin development. 
I need to develop a crossplatform (Android, ios and Windows Phone) app like the iPhone email client app in which New emails are shown on top of other emails by pulling to refresh and getting new emails from Server or a Facebook news feed style app.

I have discovered that Listview of xamarin.forms has the pull to refresh feature, but New itens gets added to the bottom of the listview, I need these itens to be added to the top of the listview... Is kind of strange having to tap "pull to refresh" on top, while New itens gets added to the end (bottom) of the listview.

Does anyone knows how to achieve that? (Show New itens on top of the listview)?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Ana Carolina

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple..

I was adding new itens to the observableCollection by using list.add(obj)... That way the item gets added to the end of the list... I changed to list.insert(0,obj) and Now the new itens are shown at the top of the listview...

☺️